# Accessing Variable effectively from shell script

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have one ini configuration file, I need to create a shell script using this configuration. What is the easiest method to access all variable, Can be used effectively from the shell script.

Can I use an array or something? Now planing to find the count of [] brackets then through awk get all variables one by one. Please suggest if any easiest way to effectively

```
cat app.ini
```

Below the output of my sample configuration file. Can be N no of Blocks.

```
[APP1]
name=Application1
StatusScript=/home/status_APP1.sh
startScript=/home/start_APP1.sh
stopScript=/home/stop_APP1.sh
restartScript=/home/restart.APP1.sh
logdir=/log/APP1/

[APP2]
name=Application2
StatusScript=/home/status_APP2.sh
startScript=/home/start_APP2.sh
stopScript=/home/stop_APP2.sh
restartScript=/home/restart.APP2.sh
logdir=/log/APP2/
.
.
.
.
.
[APPN]
name=ApplicationN
StatusScript=/home/status_APPN.sh
startScript=/home/start_APPN.sh
stopScript=/home/stop_APPN.sh
restartScript=/home/restart.APPN.sh
logdir=/log/APPN
```

/

Comment: You want to use one `[APP]` section at a time to pass some variables to another command? Can you show at least in pseudocode what the calling code looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line help us to locate particular values in each section.

```
sed -nr "/^\[APP1\]/ { :l /^name[ ]*=/ { s/.*=[ ]*//; p; q;}; n; b l;}" app.ini
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a library like bash-ini-parser https://github.com/albfan/bash-ini-parser.  It covers a lot of nuances like indentation, whitespaces, comments etc.

The example for your case may look like this:

```
 #!/bin/bash

. bash-ini-parser

cfg_parser app.ini

cfg_section_APP1
echo $name

cfg_section_APP2
echo $logdir

cfg_section_APPN
echo $logdir
```

Comment: If you are reading in variables from an external source, you should definitely use double quotes around their values when interpolating them.

Comment: I would be leery of the linked parser; the readme itself describes it as " more a hack than a reliable parser".

Comment: Very Good option, Nicely organised :)